# How to choose one of two toggle button in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, togglebutton

I have two toggle buttons in my wpf project, I want the user choose only one of them. How should I suppose to do it in MVVM.

```
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Erase_IsSelected}" />
<ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Clean_IsSelected}" />
```

Thanks！

Comment: You mean when user presses `Clean` then `Erase` becomes `Disabled`?

Comment: yes, if one IsSelected, the other one become unchecked.

Comment: Maybe you need a RadioButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're describing a RadioButton.

```
if(MyRadioButton.IsChecked == true)
{
    #do stuff
}
```

It's different from check boxes in that only one can be toggled at once, no matter how many you have. You can also use them with just one button, as an "on/off" switch for whatever you want.

You can use an else statement as well if you need it to do something special if the user doesn't check the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RadioButton` and make it look like a `ToggleButton` without too much hassle!
All you need to do is this:

```
<RadioButton Background="Blue" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Erase</RadioButton>
```

Or if you want this to be in a `Style` applied to all of the Buttons then just use this:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" TargetType="RadioButton"/>
```